# Retrieving hashed password from Keychain

Tags: password, keychain

I'm trying to retrieve a password from an old email account stored in Mac Mail from my keychain. When I view it, it gives me a "hash", it starts with "1/s....." and is 46 characters long. What is the hashing algorithm used here? How can I extract the password from it?

Comment: Do you mean Apple Mail.app? How old is the keychain item - or with other words: what was the system and Mail version then?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it was El Capitain, and the Mac Mail version was Version 9.3 (3124).

Comment: Oh, reading "old" email account I expected something like Mac OS X Panther (10.3) and Mail 1.x